# Missing keyword in Oracle select query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, inner-join

I am trying to execute this query but I am getting the following error:

```
ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 25 Column: 51
```

The query is:

```
SELECT egt.education_guarantee_type_id, egt.description, egt.is_available, egy.year_number
        FROM mo_education_guarantee_types egt
        INNER JOIN mo_education_guarantee_years egy;
```

What keyword is missing from my query?

Comment: You need a join condition, e.g INNER JOIN mo_education_guarantee_years egy ON egt.col = egy.col

Comment: You should tell it which column to join on. See [SQL Inner Join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) syntax.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2080416

Comment: Or, alternatively, change the `inner join` to a `cross join`, if you want a cartesian product of the two tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close but as jarlh said in his comment you need a join condition such as

```
SELECT egt.education_guarantee_type_id, egt.description, egt.is_available, egy.year_number
    FROM mo_education_guarantee_types egt
    INNER JOIN mo_education_guarantee_years egy ON egt.SOMEKEY = egy.SOMEKEY;
```

SOMEKEY here will refer to a field that exists in both tables.

Hope that helps.